# How to fetch value of key in array if key is of different content type

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am developing a **plugin for wordpress** which **import products for woocommerce** from a **spreadsheet using ajax**.

my spreadsheet have values of UTF-8 content type like
**Lyftrörelse**   |   **Egenhöjd**   |   **Plattformslängd**

so when i upload my file using ajax and send it to my PHP file

DATA is being Sent Correctly. but when i am fetching values from that array in my Php file like

```
$valuefirst=$productarray["Lyftrörelse"];
```

`var_dump($valuefirst);`

is returning null,
 
but if i change my value of spreadsheet to **["Lyftrorelse"]**

now when i print it like this

`$valuefirst=$productarray["Lyftrorelse"];`

`var_dump($valuefirst);`

It is printing my value,
Earlier when i was doing this without Ajax there was no such Problem,
My content was being read properly
Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting content-Type in your Ajax request,

contentType: "charset=utf-8",

Comment: actually i am using `var formData = new FormData(this);` in my ajax so in $.ajax({  i must use processData: false,  contentType: false, data: formData ... }) to send multipart form data to my php end

Comment: have a look on this :    [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) hence i must use processData: false, contentType: false,